# My puzzle which have been posted on other forum

Tags: support, moderation

I created many puzzles, before I find this site, I posted the puzzle on other forum www.brainden.com/forum. After finding this site, I see this site is more active, with more members, so I posted some puzzle which have been posted at that forum here. Today a moderator here realize that the puzzle I posted here is a copy from that forum, then delete my post immediately, to avoid copyright issue.

here is the evidence that I am the creator of the puzzle.
My profile on that forum : http://brainden.com/forum/profile/55790-jasen/?tab=field_core_pfield_11

```
About Me
You can also meet me here

http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756/jamal-senjaya
```

my puzzle there : http://brainden.com/forum/topic/17782-magic-weird-star/?#comment-344123

Can I reopen the puzzle again ?

Comment: Sorry about that! We've had a lot of plagiarism issues recently - next time, I suggest adding some text explaining that it's your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have undeleted the question for you.  To avoid this problem in the future, just add a note to your post indicating that this is your original puzzle that was originally posted elsewhere.